# Baby Rudin definition 4.5 follow up on isolated points

Tags: real-analysis

Let me start with definition 4.5:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $E \subset X, p \in E$ and $f: E \rightarrow Y$. Then $f$ is said to be continuous at $p$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(p)) < \varepsilon$ for all points $x \in E$ for which $d_X(x,p) < \delta$.

Rudin goes on to say:

> If $f$ is continuous at every point of $E$, then $f$ is said to be continuous on $E$.

and

> If $p$ is an isolated point of $E$, then our definition implies that every function $f$ which has $E$ as its domain of definition is continuous at $p$. For no matter what $\varepsilon > 0$ we choose, we can pick $\delta >0$ so that the only point $x \in E$ for which $d_X(x,p) < \delta$ is $x=p$; then $d_Y(f(x),f(p)) = 0< \varepsilon$.

In the last block, in the second sentence, I understand the conditions on the metrics, but I don't see how that shows the implication being made in the first sentence. Could someone elaborate on this further, or perhaps make it a little bit more clearer? It doesn't seem to be true to me. How is this not some sort of jump discontinuity? For example, if we have $X=\mathbb{R}$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $E=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$, and $f(x) = x^{2}$, then since $f$ is "continuous" at each point of $E$, then $f$ is continuous on $E$.  But is it not obvious that it is not continuous (just look at the graph)?

Can someone provide an example of a function having an argument that is an isolated point yet $f$ still continuous on $E$? If you can give two examples in different field(s)/metric space, that would be great. Thank you.

EDIT: I suppose if $X = E$, then it would be continuous, would it not (not totally sure)? But since our topology is in $\mathbb{R}$, how is $f$ continuous on $E$?

Comment: Your example is indeed continuous on $E$. In fact, it is continuous on $\mathbb R$, therefore at every point of $\mathbb R$, therefore on every subset of $\mathbb R$. In order for $f$ not to be continuous at $2$ (I assume this is the point you are concerned about), there would have to be some sequence of points $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$ converging to $2$, such that $f(x_n)$ fails to converge to $f(2) = 4$. But any sequence in $E$ that converges to $2$ must eventually be equal to $2$ (i.e. $x_n = 2$ for large enough $n$), in which case $f(x_n)$ eventually equals $4$, hence converges to $4$

Comment: That doesn't make sense-- at least to me. All I am getting from this is that it is both continuous and discontinuous. Okay how is the example I gave not discontinuous? I cannot draw the graph of this function without lifting my pencil off the paper. In what sense is it continuous then if you say (and I suppose the definition says) it is continuous?

Comment: The criterion "I can draw the graph of this function without lifting my pencil off the paper" isn't a suitable definition of continuity when the domain is not connected (i.e. not an interval). Indeed, it's not a very practical criterion even when the domain is an interval; e.g. try drawing the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), or the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), both of which **are** continuous.

Comment: So if we had $E = \{0\} \cup \{1\} \cup \{2\} \cup \{3\} \cup ... $ then $f$ would be continuous on $E$ (and in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: That's correct, assuming we're still talking about $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Yes, for that $f$, but the same is true for any $f$ as long as $f(x)$ is defined for each $x \in E$, right?

Comment: For $E = \{0\} \cup \{1\} \cup \{2\} \cup \cdots$ (or any $E$ consisting only of isolated points), **any** function from $E$ to any metric space is continuous. My remark "assuming we're still talking about $f(x) = x^2$" was referring to your parenthetical "(and in $\mathbb R$)".

Comment: Yes. As you may learn later in a topology class, every function whose domain is a discrete space is continuous.

Comment: What about when $f(x) = x^{2}$ as before and $E = [0,1] \cup [3,4]$, what would $f$ be on $E$? $f$ would still be continuous on $E$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$, hence continuous on any subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Remember that the definition of continuity is what you quoted in the question, not some criterion about drawing the graph with a pencil. So what Rudin does, to prove continuity at any isolated point, is to verify the definition of continuity.

Comment: Great, thank you all!